# Azure cloud service hosted website stops connecting database suddenly

Tags: sql, azure

I have a website hosted on azure cloud services. The configuration is - Java 7, Tomcat 7, SQL Azure. Nowadays I am running into a problem. Suddenly, my website stops responding to pages which require database connectivity. I have used Apache Commons DBCP for connection pooling. I have checked all the logs but I could not find any connection failure logs. I have checked the DB connections on azure portal, which also looks okay to me. Please help me out on this and let me know what other information is required.

here is sql connection configuration-

- min connections - 20
- max connections 200
- num helpers - 10

Comment: Does the database portion of your app stop responding intermittently for short periods of time or does the database portion of the app go completely "dead" for an extended period of time? If the latter, what do you then do to get it working again?

Comment: Actually, it goes in the dead state for long and to get back it to work I have to rebbot the role. But at the same time, staging is able to connect to SQL Azure.

Comment: How long are your queries?  Under what conditions does this occur?  We need more details for this particular issue.